# Find command returns no such file message for an unrelated file

Tags: files, find

My command seems to run fine. However, sometimes, it returns a message about an unrelated file not present. The directory being searched has a lot of activity and files are being created and deleted during processing.

My command:

```
find -L "$thisdir" -maxdepth 1 -name "$thisfile" -type f
```

The results are loaded into an array.

It seems the find command returns the right file name(s), but at times it tells me a file unrelated to this process does not exist.  No such file or directory.  I’m beginning to think the unrelated file is somehow part of this command due to how find works, but I cannot know for sure.

Comment: Some paths to search are symlinks.  This find is within a function, so I’m using -L in case the directory to search in is a symlink.   Are you saying I should only use -L if I know for certain that the directory name is actually a symlink?

Comment: In the case I’m seeing the odd messages, the directory being searched is not a symlink.   There is a parent directory that is a symlink, but that directory is not specified in the find command.

Answer (score -1):

You have symlinks that point to nowhere and since you used `-L` you told `find` to follow symlinks. This results in the file not found messages for the related symlinks.

So why did you use `-L`at all?